# NEAT neural network - Input and Output activation functions

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm, neat

TLTR; Does NEAT algorithm allow it's input/output layers to also evolve activation functions, or only uses identity?

I'm working on a custom NeuralNet, largely inspired by the implementation of NEAT (NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies).

As far as my experience and knowledge goes, input neurons in most networks activate without affecting the values they hold - they just pass it (identity function)
And the output layer neurons can have activation functions that are preset based on the problem that the network is trying to solve, usually it's identity, softmax or sigmoid.

For the NEAT algorithm do the inputs/outputs evolve their functions, or are they unchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes NEAT allows to "evolve" activation functions.
Which means nodes get inserted with a random activation function (you can choose what kind of activation functions to use there)

However they don't "evolve" as in the activations function changes continously. However **different nodes can have different activation function and they can mutate** (existing nodes changing activation function).

https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#defaultgenome-section

> **activation default** The default activation function attribute assigned to new nodes. If none is given, or “random” is specified, one of the activation_options will be chosen at random.
> **activation_mutate_rate** The probability that mutation will replace the node’s activation function with a randomly-determined member of the activation_options. Valid values are in [0.0, 1.0].
> **activation_options** A space-separated list of the activation functions that may be used by nodes. This defaults to sigmoid. The built-in available functions can be found in Overview of builtin activation functions; more can be added as described in Customizing Behavior

Regarding your other statement:

> As far as my experience and knowledge goes, input neurons in most
> networks activate without affecting the values they hold - they just
> pass it (identity function) And the output layer neurons can have
> activation functions that are preset based on the problem that the
> network is trying to solve, usually it's identity, softmax or sigmoid.

Actually it's the norm to have activation functions other than identity.
There is a lot of theory regarding this topic.

The gist of it is deeper networks **can be more efficient** than shallow networks. If you **only** use the **"identity function"** as an activation function, you can **rewrite a neural network of arbitrary depth to a shallow network** therefore you have virtually **no benefit** of using a **deep network (with activation function=identity function) vs a shallow network**.

Comment: Careful, I think all of this applies only to neurons in hidden layers. Input neurons simply pass input values into the network and don't usually have an activation function.

Comment: yes of course that's the definition of an input neuron. Also it doesn't only apply to the "hidden layers" it also applies to the output neurons (i think). Additionally there aren't really "layers" in networks created by NEAT.

Comment: Yes, sorry about "layers". The output neurons I don't remember if they come with a default activation in normal implementations (I think not?) but you don't want to change those either in any case (if you are using a Softmax it's because you want that type of output and so on). Also worth pointing out that mutating activation functions is not the typical use case *in general*, as far as I know (unless working with CPPNs, where it is very much the point).